# Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, smtp

Im new with php and im doing a form that send email using smtp gmail, i had a website hosten on webfreehosting.ne.

when I try to send the form i get an error : Error: SMTP connect() failed.

```
<?php
 include("class.phpmailer.php"); 
 include("class.smtp.php"); 
 $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
 $mail->IsSMTP(); 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
 $mail->Port = 465; 
 $mail->Username = "secret@gmail.com"; 
 $mail->Password = "secret";


 $maidl = $_POST["msj"];

 $mail->From = "secret@gmail.com"; 
 $mail->FromName = "Anonymous"; 
 $mail->Subject = "Anonymous "; 
 $mail->AltBody = "Anonymous   ."; 
 $mail->MsgHTML("<b> $maidl </b>.");  
 $mail->AddAddress("secret@gmail.com", "Anonymous "); 
 $mail->IsHTML(true); 
 if(!$mail->Send()) { 
 echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
 } else { 
 echo "menssage send"; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Using `tls` on port `465` makes little sense if I am not totally mistaken. Use either the standard smtp port `25` and `tls` or port `465` together with `ssl`.

Comment: i try with both and still the same error